# C# - passing in a boolean that might change elsewhere, but I don't want to change in the method

Tags: c#

i have a method that needs to react to an isCanceling flag. It should be able to be changed elsewhere and noticed within the method, but I don't want to be able to change the boolean from within the method. What I have below, I think will be able to read a bool if the passed in boolean is changed elsewhere, but I want to ensure that isCanceling cannot be changed within this context. Is that possible?

```
public static bool DoSomething(ref bool isCanceling)
{
    while(whileLoopFlag && !isCanceling)
    {
        //doTheThing()
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `ref` then?

Comment: @OmriAharon Then he doesn't have any way for external code to cancel the loop, as the bool would be copied, not referenced.

Comment: @Servy Oh, I think I completely misunderstood his question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `CancellationTokenSource`/`CancellationToken` to allow code external to this method to cancel it.  In addition to having an API where an object can notify another of cancellation, it will properly synchronize the underlying boolean such that the objects can be used from multiple threads without any problems.

Comment: Here are the links for [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the way to go.